# Timezone issue in javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on an employee time tracking application with its backend on node.js. The problem is when the site is hosted locally it registers the time in gmt +05:30 which is correct as i live in india but when i hosted the site on heroku server (which i think the heroku's server time zone is set to 00:00) and accesses it from same computer. then, it registers the time in gmt +00:00.

Now what i want is that when its hosted on heroku server it should know the time zone of the user (**Example** if user resides in Los Angeles and creates an entry. then, it should register the entry in GMT-7 timezone)

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
const postSchema = {
  username: String,
  entry: String,
  rawEntry: Number,
  exit: String,
  rawExit: Number,
  duration: String,
  complete: Boolean,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
};
```

***logEntry Route***

```
 app.get('/logEntry', function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const t = new Date();
    const now = date.format(t, 'DD/MMM/YYYY ddd hh:mm:ss A Z');
    const rawNow = Date.now();
    const post = new Post({
      username: nameUser,
      entry: now,
      rawEntry: rawNow,
      complete: false
    });
    post.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/logged');
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can store dates in UTC format and write some JS in frontend to format UTC automatically according to current viewer's locale. Those functions are in built to JS.

Comment: Please tell me the dates are ___not___ being stored as strings! They should be stored as a native date(time) type.

Comment: The entries are first calculated in native date(time) type format and then they are sent to an npm package which returns the formated date as string which i save. They are only used for the display and not for any calculation. P.S. I have edited the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by executing new Date() on the client side and then passing in url to the server for further action.

Client side code =>

```
 <button onclick="createLogin()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block entryBtn">
  CREATE LOGIN ENTRY
 </button>

   <script>
      function createLogin() {
        let t = new Date();
        console.log(t);

        let url = '/logEntry/' + t;
        window.location = url;
      }
    </script>
```

Server side code =>

```
app.get('/logEntry/:date', function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const now = req.params.date;
    const nowDayTime = now.substring(0, 25);
    const timeZone = now.substring(25, now.length);
    const rawNow = Date.now();
    const post = new Post({
      username: nameUser,
      entryDayTime: nowDayTime,
      entryTimeZone: timeZone,
      rawEntry: rawNow,
      complete: false
    });
    post.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/logged');
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem that we face with timezone.

> Client side get getTimezoneOffset and add or remove seconds that are over.

```
const d = new Date();
const n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log("your PC or laptop timezone more or less in seconds", n); // -330
```

So, when you will run this code in local that time as you told you are having **gmt +05:30** getTimezoneOffset will output -330 sec means 5 hour and 30 mins.

So you can remove these seconds from the current time and set accordingly.

## or

You can use in build javascript function

```
const d1 = new Date();
console.log(d1); //Thu Aug 29 2019 17:56:14 GMT+0530
d1.toUTCString(); // Thu, 29 Aug 2019 12:26:39 GMT
```

Check the differance is +5:30 hours.

Comment: hello binit your solution solves the second part of my problem. The first part of the problem is how to get the timezone of the user who is accessing the website from the timezone other than +5:30. 

P.S. I have edited the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: One of the best solution and people we use does not store DateTime as a string, rather than same (new Date()).getTime() and then append your offset accordingly.